# Android Studio: Display ArrayList of SQLite database rows using ListView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I have an SQLite database and I want to display each ROW/Campsite using ListView.

DBHandler method to return an ArrayList of Campsites:

```
public ArrayList<Campsite> getAllCampsites() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CAMPSITES, null);
    ArrayList<Campsite> campsites = new ArrayList<>();
    Campsite campsite;
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
            cursor.moveToNext();
            campsite = new Campsite();
            campsite.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            campsite.setCity(cursor.getString(2));
            campsite.setFeature(cursor.getString(3));
            campsite.setFavorite(cursor.getString(4));
            campsite.setRating(cursor.getInt(5));
            campsite.setLatitude(cursor.getDouble(6));
            campsite.setLongitude(cursor.getDouble(7));

            campsites.add(campsite);
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return campsites;
}
```

I have an activity called Browse which has the ListView in the layout file. I also have a browse_row_layout which has the layout for one row/campsite.

So in Browse.java I need to create the adapter to show each campsite.
Note: I am only showing 3 specific columns (name, city, feature) in the list view

So I have the activity_browse layout file which has the actual ListView element and the browse_row_layout which represents 1 row of the database and has TextViews for only 3 of the columns.

What I have so far:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Browse extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lvCampsites;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_browse);

    lvCampsites= findViewById(R.id.lvCampsites);

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    ArrayList<Campsite> campsites = db.getAllCampsites();

}
```

}

TLDR: How can I create an adapter to show each campsite from the campsite list which has each row of the database, using ListView.

Comment: this might help
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter

Comment: is there any specific need to use listview, when you can use RecyclerView

Comment: No specific need, I read about it though. Would it change how I display the data?

Comment: there is nothing special about your data, just use any *custom listview adapter* tutorial that you find on google.

Comment: Also please use `android-studio` tag only for IDE-specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom adapter class that extends the BaseAdapter and then implement the methods and then in the getView method pass the layout id to the view so that u can access the textview in the layout file.

```
public class CampsitesListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Campsites> list;

    public CampsitesListAdapter(Context mContext , List<Campsites> countries) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.list = countries;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.campsite_layout , null );
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nametxt);
        Textview city = (Textview) view.findViewById(R.id.citytxt);
        Textview feature = (Textview) view.findViewById(R.id.featuretxt);

        name.setText(list.get(position).getname());
        city.setText(list.get(position).getcity());
        feature.setText(list.get(position).getfeature());

        return view;
    }
 }
```

This is your listview activity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Browse extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lvCampsites;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_browse);

    lvCampsites= findViewById(R.id.lvCampsites);

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    ArrayList<Campsite> campsites = db.getAllCampsites();

    //Instance of custom adapter 
    CampsitesListAdapter adapter = new CampsitesListAdapter(this ,   campsites);
   //Setting adapter to listview
   lvCampsites.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I hope this might help you.

Comment: I'm sorry but how would I actually implement this in my ListView activity?

Comment: First of all create a separate class for adapter and then in your listview activity create an instance of your adapter class and pass the arraylist of campsites to the constructor of adapter and the context and then set adapter to your listview.

Comment: Well i have edited the answer i think this might help you.

Comment: Yes I was able to do it successfully just now, thanks. Now I actually want to add a onItemClickListener and make it so when a specific row is clicked, a new activity opens that shows all 7 columns instead of just 3 for that specific row. Is this possible? So basically it shows more detail about a campsite based on which campsite is clicked.

Comment: Yes for click listener simply add lvCampsites.setOnItemClickListener();

Comment: Great now you should mark the answer so that it shows that your problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

You need to first move your cursor. refer below code:

```
                         if (cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()> 0){
                            cursor.moveToFirst();
                            do{
                                Campsite campsite = new Campsite();
                                campsite.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                                campsite.setCity(cursor.getString(2));
                                campsite.setFeature(cursor.getString(3));
                                campsite.setFavorite(cursor.getString(4));
                                campsite.setRating(cursor.getInt(5));
                                campsite.setLatitude(cursor.getDouble(6));
                                campsite.setLongitude(cursor.getDouble(7));

                                campsites.add(campsite);

                            }while(cursor.moveToNext);
                        }
```

Comment: Thanks, any idea on displaying it in listview using adapter?

Comment: @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.campsite_layout , parent,false);

            return view;
        } change your getView() method like above and bind view and set text

Comment: Thanks I was able to do it by adding each campsite object to arraylist, setting up a custom list adapter, and pulling getting each campsite in setOnItemClickListner() using Campsite campsite = (Campsite) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);